# Zooming out with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to zoom out the browser and take a sceenshot of it for this I have used Python and Selenium, cloud.getdbt.com

```
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom = '50%'")
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

the screen I am getting is not I am expecting the screen seems to looks like split also the quality of screenshot is not so good.
[image]

What I am expecting is:
[image]

could someone help me with this